# Unecessary part of the graph showing in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made a simple simulator of stock prices where the price is determined by the number of buyers and sellers. For example, if there are 30 buyers and 10 sellers, 30/40 = 0,75 and 10/40 = 0,25, then the current price will increase by itself times 0,5 (0,75-0,25), that is, decrease by itself times (-0,5) if there are 10 buyers and 30 sellers.

I made it a live graph where you input the number of buyers, sellers and the number on x-axis (b, s, y) in a notepad and the graph updates itself.

Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    graph_data = open('inputs.txt','r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []

prices = [30]

for line in lines:
    if len(line) > 1:
        b, s, y = line.split(',')
        b = int(b)
        s = int(s)
        def price():
            x = prices[-1]
            pr = b / (b + s) - s / (b + s)
            global result
            result = x + x * pr
            return result

    price()
    prices.append(result)
    xs.append(y)
    ys.append(result)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)
    ax1.grid(True)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)

plt.show()
```

And this is the problem I get:

[image]

The new price is correct and is accurately charted, but then there is an additional part of the graph in a form of a straight line, which only keeps growing as I input new numbers (if the price is falling, the straight line is going down) and decreases the size of my main graph.

I don't know what I need to change in my code for that line not to show, or how i could remove it. I would really appreciate the answer.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Can you provide a [mcve] which includes the data and has the correct indentation in the code?

Comment: There needs to be a .txt document in the folder where the program is saved (in my code inputs.txt) with a rows of three numbers, for example: 30,10,0; 20,10,1; 15,20,2,... the problem shows with every graph, not with just the one on the picture.

Comment: I understand that. But as I said, I cannot reproduce it, meaning that I do not get a straight line when I run your code. See [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLRoa.png).

Comment: That line does not show when you input the same number of buyers and sellers, that is, when the price remains the same, only when it falls or raises. Sorry if I am making this hard :(

Comment: Again I cannot reproduce it, even if the last line is different. See [updated picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxdcO.png).

Comment: I used the same numbers as you, but I still get the same problem. Which version of Python are you using? I have just tryed running the code from different versions and from a different computer, but it is the same.

Comment: I'm on windows 8, python 2.7 with matplotlib version 2.0.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, but thank you very much for your time :)